# Trying to append values to an array within a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am attempting to add elements to an array defined within a Dictionary as follows:

```
var eventsByQuarter = Dictionary<Int, [D_MatchEvents]>()
```

The dictionary holds the details of events in a sports match where the key is the quarter of the match concerned. i.e. every event for quarter 1 is in the array assigned to this dictionary item (I will use the dictionary later as the data source for a table view with 4 sections).

`D_MatchEvents` is defined by `Core Data` and has a many-to-one relationship with a `MatchData` entity. The 'quarter' for each event is already captured as one of the attributes within the `MatchEvents` entity.

```
func loadMatchEvents() {
    match = DatabaseController.fetchMatch(matchUUID)!
    matchEvents = match?.r_ToEvents?.allObjects as! [D_MatchEvents]
    matchEvents = matchEvents.sorted() {($0.d_EventTimestamp?.compare($1.d_EventTimestamp as! Date) == .orderedAscending)}

    for event in matchEvents {
        eventsByQuarter[event.d_EventQuarter] = eventsByQuarter.append(event)
    }
}
```

`matchEvents` is correctly loaded as a sorted array of type `D_MatchEvents`, but when I try to loop through the array appending each event to the correct "quarter" array in the Dictionary I get an ambiguous error when trying to reference member 'subscript'.

I cannot see how I can achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `d_EventQuarter` of type `Int`?

Comment: In fact it is type Int16? as Core Data does not allow Int

Comment: I am afk im the moment but I assume unwrapping it will fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure of your Dictionary, the problem is here:

```
for event in matchEvents {
    eventsByQuarter[event.d_EventQuarter] = eventsByQuarter.append(event)
}
```

It should really be:

```
for event in matchEvents {
    eventsByQuarter[event.d_EventQuarter]?.append(event)
}
```

Though you really need to check to see if there even *is* an existing array for the given key, so I'd do something like this:

```
for event in matchEvents {
    //Create a variable that is either a mutable copy of the existing array, or a new, empty array of the correct type
    var thisQuarter = eventsByQuarter[event.d_eventQuarter] ?? [D_MatchEvents]()
    //Add the new item
    thisQuarter.append(event)
    //Replace the existing array with the appended copy, or add a new key-value pair (if it didn't already exist)
    eventsByQuarter[event.d_eventQuarter] = thisQuarter
}
```

Not super efficient, but it's a quick implementation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. it got me looking further into it. I have found the solution now. In fact, what I needed to do was to define the key as its own variable rather than referring directly to an element of the array. So the code now looks like this

```
    for event in matchEvents {
        let qtr:Int = Int(event.d_EventQuarter)
        eventsByQuarter[qtr]?.append(event)
    }
```

I'm not sure why this would be the case, but it works. One of many mysteries still to discover using SWIFT! Regarding your other comment about checking whether a dictionary item exists before appending, I agree fully in other cases, however here, I know that there'll always be 4 items, no more no less, so have elected simply to initialise them at the outset, then no further checking is necessary. I just do this before looping through the array to set up the dictionary.

```
       for index in 1...4 { eventsByQuarter[index] = [] }
```